Specifying Anaconda install in VSCode on Windows OS
I have two versions of conda installed. I have a default profile linked to ARcGIS conda. I have been using this conda installation until recently with VSCode. I installed another version of conda that wasn't linked to ArcGIS because of tensorflow conflicts. I created a new profile called tf that I linked to another conda environment outside of ArcGIS conda. However, VSCode only recognizes the ArcGIS conda environments, even when I set the default conda environment to tf. The ArcGIS pro conda installation can be referenced from the command prompt on Windows (cmd). The native anaconda installation can only be accessed through Anaconda navigator window. When I type conda env list at the command prompt outside of Anaconda navigator, I can see the path to my new conda environment and my ArcGIS environments, but there is no name associated with the new environment tf. How can I get VSCode to use the conda installation outside of ArcGIS?
I have tried eliminating all the references to the ArcGIS conda environments in VSCode, but the terminal is still only recognizing ArcGIS conda environments.
